# Redis-Cli cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:6379, but redis-stack runs fine

Tags: redis, port, redis-cluster

I had Redis up and running a few weeks and had no issues. I have returned to it today and am getting some problems connecting to any port and I cannot create a new database on any port from Redis Insight [Redis Insight Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x57x.jpg).

If I run redis-server or redis-stack-server it works, however when I enter redis-cli: I get the error:

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Can't assign requested address.

Wondering if anyone knows how to fix this? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Redis but nothing has worked.

Comment: Check your redis.conf file and see if the "bind" config has value of 127.0.0.1 or something else

Comment: yes it has that value